# How can I totally remove an app from my account?

Tags: applications, ios-appstore

I had downloaded a free app and now I don’t need it.
I want to remove it from purchase list. I don’t want to hide it, I want to totally remove it from the purchase and from the hidden purchases as well.

Can I do this without contacting Apple?

Answer (score 6):

Purchase records are permanent. You can hide them but not delete them. Only Apple support could grant this request.

This is common functionality (you can hide but not delete) with the iTunes music store, [iOS App Store](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201322), [Books store](https://support.apple.com/guide/books/hide-and-unhide-purchased-items-ibksa4e88313/mac) and the [macOS App Store](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/294716/5472). You can open a support case with apple of somehow you have an exceptional need for this, but I would expect they wouldn’t intervene.

There is one exception to this, the U2 situation. Apple had so many requests to remove that free gift “purchase” that the had a web form to automate that for 5 or so years. That exception form is down and you again have to request it specifically from support.

- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251184844

Let us know if you have success with support.

Comment: It's quite astonishing that Apple doesn't give users control over what apps they associate with. [This](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/42081/290197) particularly concerns me. Especially [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42079/how-to-uninstall-a-program-through-the-app-store#comment305125_42081): *The problem with these approaches is that even deleted applications will still attempt to upgrade themselves through the App Store. This is at best annoying, and at worst will lead to their accidental reinstallation.*